IIS Not Serving Files from /assets/node_modules/ - How to Redirect to Main Page
I'm deploying my application to IIS, and I'm encountering an issue where IIS is not able to read or serve files from the /assets/node_modules/ directory. When the application tries to load resources like fonts from this path, it fails.
I attempted to redirect /assets/node_modules/ to /, but it was unsuccessful.


How did you deploy the web app? The folder node_modules shouldn’t appear in production if you deploy a release build.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
